# What do those orange stripes in the Lagometer mean in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Actually, my game is running nearly perfectly, but sometimes there are these screen freezes... I don't know what the problem is, because the graphics card is not used nor the processor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### As shown in this post on Reddit (the top reply):

*https://www.reddit.com/r/Optifine/comments/h9selj/comment/fuysx7t/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3*

It's java's garbage collection.

The screen freezes could be chunks loading in and out.